# Automatically switch between different display scaling in tablet vs desktop mode for 2-in-1 laptops on Windows10/11

Tags: windows, windows-11, touchscreen, display-settings

In 2-in-1 laptop/tablets, Windows 10 and 11 can recognize with onboard hardware sensors when a display is folded back which triggers tablet conversion.

I want my display scaling to be 200% for **desktop mode** and 225% for **tablet mode** so that the UI elements get easy to click on touch-screen.

I'm looking for a program/script/system tweak which can **automatically set the display scaling** depending on the current mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to write a C++ program with this functionality which is working perfectly as I expected.
I used the open source tool [SetDPI](https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI) mentioned in previous answer to set the DPI for the main display.
**Usage:** `SetDPI.exe [monitor no] [DPI scale value]`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

bool isTabletMode() {
    return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CONVERTIBLESLATEMODE) == 0;
}
void setTabletScaling() {
    WinExec("C:\\Programs\\SetDpi.exe 1 225", SW_HIDE);
}
void setDesktopScaling() {
    WinExec("C:\\Programs\\SetDpi.exe 1 200", SW_HIDE);
}
int main() {
    bool currentMode, lastMode = isTabletMode();
    while (true) {
        currentMode = isTabletMode();
        if (currentMode && !lastMode) {
            setTabletScaling();
        } 
        else if (!currentMode && lastMode) {
            setDesktopScaling();
        }
        lastMode = currentMode;
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will loop, checking the registry key for the
mode every second, and will set the DPI accordingly.
As I'm not using a tablet, I couldn't fully test the script.

It uses the open-source project of
[SetDPI](https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI).
You should download the utility from the Release page.
In my test script, this is located in `C:\Temp\SetDpi.exe`.

I also assume that this refers to your primary monitor, which is the
first monitor, so numbered `1`.

```
#Persistent
lastmode = -1
SetTimer, checkmode, 1000
return

checkmode:
RegRead, mode, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell, TabletMode
if mode = lastmode
  return
if mode = 0
  Run, C:\Temp\SetDpi.exe 1 200, , Hide    ; desktop mode
else
  Run, C:\Temp\SetDpi.exe 1 225, , Hide    ; tablet mode
lastmode = mode
return
```

If instead of a loop, you prefer using hotkeys to change the DPI,
use the following simplified script, where
F11 sets the DPI to 200 and F12 to 225:

```
F11::Run, C:\Temp\SetDpi.exe 1 200, , Hide
F12::Run, C:\Temp\SetDpi.exe 1 225, , Hide
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Yes, I have only one display. Unfortunately, your first code (without hotkey) doesn't work.
Maybe the way you tried to detect desktop/tablet mode doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. I checked, and there are dozens of sources to be found that point to this registry item as the indicator for Tablet Mode. Perhaps this has changed. For future readers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498124/165358) is an alternative AutoHotKey script.